# MySql Workbenc Developer Default option

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

Im learning PHP through a book and it asked me to install MySql Installer and choose Developer Default option, But I dont get that option, how do I solve this
Thanks if anyone can help.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfWZt.jpg)

I tried installing mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.34.0
and mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.42.0 but get same screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Complete the Download of MYSQL with Select the Full Option as that will get you the database server and client tools of developer option as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).